# Slightly chance of something

Tags: grammaticality

On multiple occasions I heard the phrase *slightly chance of something* (e.g. rain). This sounds wrong as *slightly* is an adverb.

[Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22slightly%20chance%22) returns only few instances. Is it acceptable to use this in speech, is it slang, or just mistake that some people make?

Comment: Are you sure it's not something like _a slightly greater chance of rain_? Adverb look-alikes (traditionally still called adverbs by many) are often used to modify adjectives (and true adverbs). But we need some examples, please.

Comment: I indeed heard it said like stated in OP. You can even find few examples in google search, it isn’t very frequent though.

It confused me, that my friend texted me this phrase and I remembered hearing it few times before, but it sounds weird (due to the adverbial nature of the first word). I thought that maybe some people just omit the comparative when speaking but it might be as well mistake. Anyway it shouldn’t appear in writing.

Comment: Also do you have any resource comparing *adverb look-alikes* with *adverbs*? I never heard of them and can’t find anything about them.

Comment: 'Adverb' is a common term for a part of speech; 'adverb look-alike' isn't. [This article](https://www.sussex.ac.uk/webteam/gateway/file.php?name=essay---parts-of-speech.pdf&site=1) separates degree modifiers ('secondary modifiers, of adjectives / adverbs' is a more fitting term: _very_ slow / slowly; _eerily_ silent) from the 'adverb' catch-all. It also gives a special mention to 'sentence adverbs' (eg _Frankly_, I'd sell it) which others class as pragmatic markers. 'Sentence connectors' (eg 'However') can also be classed as pragmatic markers. +'Prep'l phrase modifiers' & 'limiting modifiers'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a mistake. *Chance*, as a noun, is modified by the adjective, *slight*, rather than by an adverb, *slightly*.